# C Wrapper Calling Fortran Functions

Tags: c, fortran, gfortran, fortran-iso-c-binding

I'm trying to write a C wrapper to call a set of functions in a Fortran module.  I'm starting with something basic but I'm missing something important.

I've tried appending/prepending different numbers of underscores.  I've also tried linking with gcc instead of gfortran.  What I show below gives the simplest error(s).

I'm working on a Mac running Yosemite 10.10.3, GNU Fortran 5.1.0, and the C compiler that comes with Xcode.

**main.c**

```
#include "stdio.h"

int main(void) 
{
    int a;
    float b;
    char c[30];
    extern int _change_integer(int *a);

    printf("Please input an integer: ");
    scanf("%d", &a);

    printf("You new integer is: %d\n", _change_integer(&a));

    return 0;
}
```

**intrealstring.f90**

```
module intrealstring
use iso_c_binding
implicit none

contains

integer function change_integer(n)
    implicit none

    integer, intent(in) :: n
    integer, parameter :: power = 2

    change_integer = n ** power
end function change_integer

end module intrealstring
```

**Here is how I'm compiling, along with the error:**

```
$ gcc -c main.c
$ gfortran -c intrealstring.f90
$ gfortran main.o intrealstring.o -o cwrapper
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "__change_integer", referenced from:
      _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
$
```

Comment: error suggests your mixing 32bit and 64bit code?

Comment: Always use tag [tag:fortran], use the tags for individual versions only if you want to stress you don't want any newer standard version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You have to bind fortran to c:**

```
module intrealstring
use iso_c_binding
implicit none

contains

integer (C_INT) function change_integer(n) bind(c)
    implicit none

    integer (C_INT), intent(in) :: n
    integer (C_INT), parameter :: power = 2

    change_integer = n ** power
end function change_integer

end module intrealstring
```

**Your c file has to modified as follows:**

```
#include "stdio.h"

int change_integer(int *n);

int main(void) 
{
    int a;
    float b;
    char c[30];

    printf("Please input an integer: ");
    scanf("%d", &a);

    printf("You new integer is: %d\n", change_integer(&a));

    return 0;
}
```

**The you can do:**

```
$ gcc -c main.c
$ gfortran -c intrealstring.f90
$ gfortran main.o intrealstring.o -o cwrapper
```

Comment: Thank you, Vladimir.  Your solution works.  In the Fortran function change_integer, the parameter "power" is local.  Is the binding to C still necessary or is it just good programming practice to bind all declarations to C?

Comment: I think you are asking your question to me. Yes, you can avoid to bind power variable, because of is local. I used to use bindings always when I write wrappers. It is a personal rule to avoid to forget bindings where is mandatory. Set the answer as correct to avoid other people waste time, please.

Comment: The question was for anyone with experience.  I tested it myself and found it is not required but I agree with your reasoning. Thank you LPs for your reply and your guidance in managing my questions.